# cant increase docker volume size in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am using t2.xlarge instance on AWS-EC2, and every time I am trying to build docker image or pull an image, I get 'no space left on device error'.

So I added another volume storage to the instance, and when running `df` on it the result is:
`Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on`
`udev             8207748       0   8207748   0% /dev`
`tmpfs            1643144  173048   1470096  11% /run`
`/dev/xvda1       8065444 7934444    114616  99% /`
`tmpfs            8215704       4   8215700   1% /dev/shm`
`tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock`
`tmpfs            8215704       0   8215704   0% /sys/fs/cgroup`
`tmpfs            1643144       0   1643144   0% /run/user/1000`
`tmpfs            1643144       0   1643144   0% /run/user/113`

As you can see, there is a lot of empty space, but one volume is 99% used, and I guess this is the one docker using.

Docker info command gave this:

```html
Containers: 3
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfd04396dc68220d1cecbe686a6cc3aa5ce3667c
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1049-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.67GiB
Name: ip-172-31-3-56
ID: GEWL:ZJ63:YSSV:MLFO:2Y2B:DRID:A6VF:JLRT:RMLK:2QRS:42K4:6XC2
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: yogevglucome
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I read from several blogs about resizing the daemon basesize, but this went wrong as well:

```
ERRO[2018-05-09T12:41:33.103398510Z] [graphdriver] prior storage driver overlay2 failed: overlay2: unknown option dm.basesize
```

Can someone help me with this one please?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you cleaned unused volume and images? if not the docker system prune will help you to do this job.

Comment: Yes, I did. cleared 0B.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issue, and figured out that root-volume was 99% full, I followed

1. [AWS EC2 root volume increase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html)
2. [extend file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

after this, `docker pull` worked fine. **Make sure that the root volume has enough free space** even though you are running `docker pull` on within a directory attached to different volume

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont put a cron job that clean server with the docker prune --all
It will delete all not used images including dangling images.

It is better to clean up that pay for more resources

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Comment: I did.
I have one running container, which is postgres, and I want to have another one more application for testing with it. The problem is, that I don't want to remove the image when I am done with it, I want docker to use the layers in it while building a newer version of the app.